# WPdatatables in combination with OnePress theme (bootstrap dropdown issue)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am really struggling with a Wordpress installation with the OnePress theme and use of WPdatatables plugin.

Everything is working flawlessly except for the dropdowns 
- number of rows
- Filter by "genre"

There are no console errors whatsoever but the dropdowns are 1) not properly rendered and 2) I see the native dropdown caret and the bootstrap one.

I tried playing with custom css for hours with z-index as I presume this may be the culprit but am losing it right now.

See https://www.concordegand.be/bcweb-bibliotheque/

Does anyone have any pointers for me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself:

Found out that OnePress theme uses Bootstrap 4 Alpha version. I modified core files so it uses Bootstrap 3.3.7 and all works fine now!